# Image Load based on state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image

[image]

I want to load an image based on the state which I am getting from API call. For example, if the API gives me `'1'`, I want to load `1.png`. Unfortunately I am getting the above error.

Here is my code

```
let img = info.WeatherIcon ? require(`../../img/icons/${info.WeatherIcon}.png`) : require('../../img/icons/7.png')
< Image style = {{ width:120, height:120}} source = { img } />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dynamic links. According to React-Native, all your image sources need to be loaded before compiling your bundle.

So change your code as below,

```
let img =
  info.WeatherIcon == "1"
    ? require("../../img/icons/1.png")
    : require("../../img/icons/7.png");
```

then you can render your `Image`

```
<Image style={{ width: 120, height: 120 }} source={img} />
```

For more complicate example you can use condition as below,

```
switch (info.WeatherIcon) {
  case "1":
    return require("../../img/icons/1.png");
  case "2":
    return require("../../img/icons/2.png");
  case "3":
    return require("../../img/icons/3.png");
  default:
    return require("../../img/icons/7.png");
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts

Comment: i have more than 50 images.. Its tedious work? any other Alternative?

Comment: @MuhammadSami that's how react-native works. but you can try to create a custom component to render an image using ```react.PureComponent``` or ```react.memo``` when passing an individual image from API.